# Store old password hashes in Django, so Users can't reuse the same password

Tags: python, django, hash, passwords

Is there a way to Store old password hashes in Django, so Users can't reuse the same password?

When doing research on this, every time Django creates a password hash, the hash is different, even though the password is the same.  For example, this will return two different hashes:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
make_password('foo')
make_password('foo')
```

I can understand the security reason for this.  Have anyone tried to do this in Django?  To store old passwords in some way, so Users will have to use a new password when their passwords expire, etc...?

Comment: anyway the reason this happens it it uses a salt when it makes the password im sure in the SETTINGS you can specify a constant salt to use instead of a new one each time ...

Comment: @Aaron Did you find a way to do this? Even i am planing to implement storing.. Please let me know if you have found any solution for the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
make_password("foo",salt="bar")
```

but storing historic hashes is really really annoying ...

Answer (score 6):

Not sure still relevant for you but will be for others sure.
You can store all previous hash and then compare each one with the same function Django does:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password
check_password("plain_password", "hash_stored")
```

the best idea is to add this check to a custom password validation as Django suggest in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/passwords/ end of the doc

Something like this:

```
class InvalidPasswordReused:
    number_of_passw_not_allowed = settings.PASSWORDS_HASH_STORED

    def __init__(self, number_of_prev_passw_not_allowed=6):
        self.number_of_prev_passw_not_allowed = number_of_prev_passw_not_allowed
        pass

    def validate(self, password, user=None):
        if user.previous_passwords:
            previous_passwords = list(user.previous_passwords)
            for prev_passw in previous_passwords:
                if check_password(password, prev_passw):
                    raise ValidationError(
                        f"Password cannot be one of the {self.number_of_prev_passw_not_allowed} last passwords.",
                        code='passwor_reused_not_allowed'
                    )
        return None

    def get_help_text(self):
        return f"Password cannot be one of the {self.number_of_prev_passw_not_allowed} last passwords."
```

Comment: My validations require user instance but I always get None in user, Any idea how can I pass user inside validate method? @jibarlia?

Comment: @AdnanSheikh are you calling check password with the user, user_instance.check_password(password)?